# Create Class functions on the fly?

Tags: php, oop

i have a validation class which needs improving. If I require some custom validation I need to specify a custom function. It works a bit like this:

1. The controller tells the validation that a custom validation function is required.
2. The controller runs the validation.
3. --- Gets iffy here ---
4. Validation class creates a new instance of the controller class....
5. Validation class runs controller->custom_validation_function()
6. Validation class returns true / false

Is there someway that I can alter this to do something like this?

```
$validation = new validation;
// Insert rules here.
$validation->function() = $this->function();
```

By doing this I could get rid of the step of creating an unneeded class instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to use a [Strategy Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy). Have a Validator class for each validation you want to do and then instantiate this class in the consuming class as needed. Then delegate the validation to the validator instance.

Have a look at [how Zend Framework does](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.introduction.html) it for an idea.
Also see the example given in my answer to this related question:

- [Can I include code into a PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957732/can-i-include-code-into-a-php-class/1957830#1957830)

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't really support `monkeypatching`, but you could create either a subclass and use that as your `$validation` object (this is the way I would do it). Or you could figure out a way to use __call to do it: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the delegates [example](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/29425.html) at phpclasses.com.

```
$processruns->add(function() { echo "hello"; });
$processruns->add(function() { echo "world"; });
```

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48570/something-like-a-callback-delegate-function-in-php) discussion might help.

Comment: But can you call `$this` from those functions?

Comment: @SeanJA: Haven't used it though, but I suppose you can call it like `$processruns->add(function() { $this->yourfunction(); });`