# how do i define delegate in php

Tags: php, delegates

How do I define a function within a class and method is empty,
method would change the calling class (as delegate in c#)
The following error codes are:

```
class myclass{
      public $num1=0;
      public function func($a,$b);
}
$c=new myclass();
$c->func=function($a,$b){
      return $a+$b;
}
$c->func(4,8);// is error
```

Comment: I think this would help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48570/something-like-a-callback-delegate-function-in-php

Comment: In PHP there are callbacks (same as delegates in C#) - [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class myclass {
      public $num1=0;
      public function func($a,$b,$fn) {
            return $fn($a,$b); // return anonymous function
      }
}

$c = new myclass();

$c->func(2,5,function($a,$b) { // declaring anonymous function with $a and $b parameters
    echo $a + $b; // result 7
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/h9v85S)</kbd>